# Problem with out parameter in web service function call

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I have the following function in my web service:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
 public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";

        }

        [WebMethod]
        public void Login(string url, string id, out int ClientType, out int ClientID)
        {
            ClientID = 11;
            ClientType = 12;
        }
    }
}
```

On the client side I see it in object reference without the out parameter this is the whole code  , I am interested in `public void Login(string url, string id, out int ClientType, out int ClientID)`  , I just want to use in on the client side with as I see it on the server side.What changes I should do in the server that I will puslish It with out changes.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference1 {


    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="ServiceReference1.Service1Soap")]
    public interface Service1Soap {

        // CODEGEN: Generating message contract since element name HelloWorldResult from namespace http://tempuri.org/ is not marked nillable
        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld", ReplyAction="*")]
        ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference1.HelloWorldResponse HelloWorld(ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference1.HelloWorldRequest request);

        // CODEGEN: Generating message contract since element name url from namespace http://tempuri.org/ is not marked nillable
        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/Login", ReplyAction="*")]
        ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference1.LoginResponse Login(ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference1.LoginRequest request);
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(IsWrapped=false)]
    public partial class HelloWorldRequest {

        [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Name="HelloWorld", Namespace="http://tempuri.org/", Order=0)]
        public ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference1.HelloWorldRequestBody Body;

        public HelloWorldRequest() {
        }

        public HelloWorldRequest(ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference1.HelloWorldRequestBody Body) {
            this.Body = Body;
        }
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute()]
    public partial class HelloWorldRequestBody {

        public HelloWorldRequestBody() {
        }
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(IsWrapped=false)]
    public partial class HelloWorldResponse {

        [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Name="HelloWorldResponse", Namespace="http://tempuri.org/", Order=0)]
        public ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference1.HelloWorldResponseBody Body;

        public HelloWorldResponse() {
        }

        public HelloWorldResponse(ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference1.HelloWorldResponseBody Body) {
            this.Body = Body;
        }
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Namespace="http://tempuri.org/")]
    public partial class HelloWorldResponseBody {

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(EmitDefaultValue=false, Order=0)]
        public string HelloWorldResult;

        public HelloWorldResponseBody() {
        }

        public HelloWorldResponseBody(string HelloWorldResult) {
            this.HelloWorldResult = HelloWorldResult;
        }
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(IsWrapped=false)]
    public partial class LoginRequest {

        [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Name="Login", Namespace="http://tempuri.org/", Order=0)]
        public ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference1.LoginRequestBody Body;

        public LoginRequest() {
        }

        public LoginRequest(ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference1.LoginRequestBody Body) {
            this.Body = Body;
        }
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Namespace="http://tempuri.org/")]
    public partial class LoginRequestBody {

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(EmitDefaultValue=false, Order=0)]
        public string url;

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(EmitDefaultValue=false, Order=1)]
        public string id;

        public LoginRequestBody() {
        }

        public LoginRequestBody(string url, string id) {
            this.url = url;
            this.id = id;
        }
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(IsWrapped=false)]
    public partial class LoginResponse {

        [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Name="LoginResponse", Namespace="http://tempuri.org/", Order=0)]
        public ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference1.LoginResponseBody Body;

        public LoginResponse() {
        }

        public LoginResponse(ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference1.LoginResponseBody Body) {
            this.Body = Body;
        }
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Namespace="http://tempuri.org/")]
    public partial class LoginResponseBody {

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(Order=0)]
        public int ClientType;

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(Order=1)]
        public int ClientID;

        public LoginResponseBody() {
        }

        public LoginResponseBody(int ClientType, int ClientID) {
            this.ClientType = ClientType;
            this.ClientID = ClientID;
        }
    }

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    public interface Service1SoapChannel : ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference1.Service1Soap, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel {
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    public partial class Service1SoapClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference1.Service1Soap>, ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference1.Service1Soap {

        public Service1SoapClient() {
        }

        public Service1SoapClient(string endpointConfigurationName) : 
                base(endpointConfigurationName) {
        }

        public Service1SoapClient(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) : 
                base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
        }

        public Service1SoapClient(string endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
                base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
        }

        public Service1SoapClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
                base(binding, remoteAddress) {
        }

        [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
        ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference1.HelloWorldResponse ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference1.Service1Soap.HelloWorld(ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference1.HelloWorldRequest request) {
            return base.Channel.HelloWorld(request);
        }

        public string HelloWorld() {
            ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference1.HelloWorldRequest inValue = new ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference1.HelloWorldRequest();
            inValue.Body = new ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference1.HelloWorldRequestBody();
            ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference1.HelloWorldResponse retVal = ((ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference1.Service1Soap)(this)).HelloWorld(inValue);
            return retVal.Body.HelloWorldResult;
        }

        [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
        ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference1.LoginResponse ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference1.Service1Soap.Login(ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference1.LoginRequest request) {
            return base.Channel.Login(request);
        }

        public int Login(string url, string id, out int ClientID) {
            ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference1.LoginRequest inValue = new ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference1.LoginRequest();
            inValue.Body = new ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference1.LoginRequestBody();
            inValue.Body.url = url;
            inValue.Body.id = id;
            ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference1.LoginResponse retVal = ((ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference1.Service1Soap)(this)).Login(inValue);
            ClientID = retVal.Body.ClientID;
            return retVal.Body.ClientType;
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea why I dont see the out parameter there, and why I cannot use it?

Comment: Slight tangent, but why doesn't Login just return ClientID?

Comment: @ forsvarir: but if I will have there 2 out parameters what then ?

Comment: Also... The class you've posted is a request body... if you think about it, what would an out parameter be doing in the request?  It *might* be part of the response, if the tooling was setup that way...

Comment: @Night Walker: You'd return an appropriate class that contained the relevant information in it?

Comment: What's the signature of the method on the client side? What does it return?

Comment: You're not necessarily going to see the same signature on the client as on the server. There's no reason for it to be the same.

Comment: @John Saunders , I am trying to mimic some web service , and  in the calling application they call the original web service like m_Machine.Login("String", "String", 5, out m_ClientID); , And I need to make a function with the same signature .

Comment: Then you need to make such a function. The proxy creation code won't necessarily make one for you.

Comment: @John Saunders: You mean to write one on the client side proxy? I just want to publish a function with  exact same signature ,any idea how original web server got this signature ?

Comment: Yes, just write one in client side code that calls the proxy version.

Comment: @John Saunders   , the problem is that I cannot change the client size , I can make changes only In my server (I men in the web service).Sounds little bit strange how in the original service they been able to get a function with this signature and I just cannot do it .

Comment: Wait, do you have the WSDL from the original service? If so, run it through WSDL /serverInterface, which will generate a C# interface which, if you implement it, will produce a service with the same WSDL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of John Saunders , thanks again , I know what to search .

I have found this answer [how to generate web service out of wsdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394930/how-to-generate-web-service-out-of-wsdl)

And It was exactly what I needed .

Answer (score 1):

I think this similar question might help you out.

[Is it unusual for a web service call to have an "out" parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590002/is-it-unusual-for-a-web-service-call-to-have-an-out-parameter)

Also, you could just make a struct or class that bundles up your two out parameters and returns it something like this.

```
public class LoginResult
{
    public LoginResult(int clientType, int clientId)
    {
         ClientType = clientType;
         ClientID = clientId;
    }

    public int ClientType { get; set; };
    public int ClientID{ get; set; };
}

[WebMethod]        
public LoginResult Login(string url, string id)
{
    return new LoginResult( 11, 12 );      
}
```

Comment: so what I can do on the web service side , that I will be able to make the calls with the out parameters ?

Comment: It looks like the method isn't exposed on the object or something. Can you post the class code that contains the method. That might help with debugging.

Comment: I have put also the webservice class .

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.
The code looks fine so I did some digging and found an article that might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590002/is-it-unusual-for-a-web-service-call-to-have-an-out-parameter

Comment: What it doesn't tell you is how to execute it from javascript, but the link shows how you can parse the response from the webrequest.

Answer (score 0):

It will be in the `LoginResponseBody`. IIRC the method will be modified on the client side so that it returns a value. Or maybe inside `LoginRequest`.